# Style not working Material Design Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-error

I was just making App UI and my app crashes

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.quizmaker

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quiz_app"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#363A43"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="@string/welcome"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#7A8089"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/please_enter_your_name"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#363A43"
                    android:textColorHint="#7A8089"
                    android:hint="@string/name"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/start"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.QuizMaker" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <!--        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>-->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my manifesta file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.quizmaker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.QuizMaker">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle-Module File

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quizmaker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

```
                 **Error I got**
```

```
2021-05-08 18:41:46.342 8173-8173/com.example.quizmaker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quizmaker, PID: 8173
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quizmaker/com.example.quizmaker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61 in com.example.quizmaker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #61 in com.example.quizmaker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61 in com.example.quizmaker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #61 in com.example.quizmaker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61 in com.example.quizmaker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.quizmaker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-05-08 18:41:46.344 8173-8173/com.example.quizmaker E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTextAppearance(ThemeEnforcement.java:187)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:118)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:463)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:422)
            ... 32 more
2021-05-08 18:41:46.451 8173-8173/com.example.quizmaker I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8173 SIG: 9
```

I have added all required dependencies.

When I debug and remove one line from my code my app doesn't crash and work the line I removed is

```
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

But when I visit to Material Design page there I found this syntax is correct but I don't know what wrong I am doing.
S0, Please help me in resolving this Error.

Comment: Post your app theme

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have added this in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity is using:

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

You have to switch to a MaterialComponents theme.

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

**What's Happening?**

`MainActivity` is extended with `NoActionBarTheme` and it's is not extending the Material Theme which is causing this crash.

**Solution**

**Step 1**: Add material theme dependency (if not added)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

**Step 2**: Extend your App Theme and Activity Theme to Material Theme.

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**Step 3**: Now you can use `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` in your `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: I have added this in my File

Comment: I have edited my question, please recheck.